# populate NamedDomainObjectContainer from file

Tags: gradle

Suppose I am currently authoring a Gradle plugin, and I have this extension:

```kotlin
abstract class MyExtension {
    abstract val inputFiles: ConfigurableFileCollection
    val names: Provider<List<String>> by lazy {
        // Read input files to get a list of names
        inputFiles.elements.map { ... }
    }
    
    abstract val instances: NamedDomainObjectContainer<MyType>
}
```

What I want to do in my plugin is to make sure that every name provided by `names` is registered in `instances` if not already registered. That is, something like this:

```kotlin
names.get().forEach {
    if (!instances.names.contains(it)) {
        instances.register(it) {
            // Additional configuration goes here
        }
    }
}
```

I have heard that `project.afterEvaluate()` is an option, however I have also heard that it is a bad option that shouldn't be used. What would be a way to have this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another `DomainObjectContainer`, which has [various functionality](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DomainObjectCollection.html) to allow it to stay up-to-date with other objects being configured.

For instance you could have the extension class:

```
abstract class MyExtension {
    abstract val inputFiles: ConfigurableFileCollection
    abstract val names: DomainObjectSet<String>
    abstract val instances: NamedDomainObjectContainer<MyType>
}
```

Then have in your plugin code:

```
val ext = project.extensions.create("MyExtension", MyExtension::class.java)
ext.names.all { eachName ->
    ext.instances.register(eachName) {
        // Additional config
    }
}
ext.names.addAllLater(ext.inputFiles.elements.map { ... })
```

The lambda passed to `all` will be executed for each new name added to `names`, including all the files, so all the collections will stay current with each other.

Comment: That doesn't work quite fine for me, adding a file to `inputFiles` does not populate `names` or `instances` for me. Is it because the names list is not fully realized after the file is added?

Comment: It appears that the `all` has to come before `addLater` in order to work. Odd.

Comment: Yes, I've been looking at and I get exactly the same behaviour. I've amended the answer to show the working method and reported the bug to Gradle: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/23904